# Phonegap - updated version pg-plugin-screen-orientation?

Tags: plugins, cordova, screen, orientation

Plugin Link: [pg-plugin-screen-orientation](https://github.com/champierre/pg-plugin-screen-orientation)

I tried to updated it but it doesn't work at all. Here is my updated version (Java):

```java
package com.tsukurusha.phonegap.plugins;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;

import org.apache.cordova.api.CordovaPlugin;
import org.apache.cordova.api.PluginResult;

public class ScreenOrientation extends CordovaPlugin {
    // Refer to http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#screenOrientation

    private static final String UNSPECIFIED = "unspecified";
    private static final String LANDSCAPE = "landscape";
    private static final String PORTRAIT = "portrait";
    private static final String USER = "user";
    private static final String BEHIND = "behind";
    private static final String SENSOR = "sensor";
    private static final String NOSENSOR = "nosensor";
    private static final String SENSOR_LANDSCAPE = "sensorLandscape";
    private static final String SENSOR_PORTRAIT = "sensorPortrait";
    private static final String REVERSE_LANDSCAPE = "reverseLandscape";
    private static final String REVERSE_PORTRAIT = "reversePortrait";
    private static final String FULL_SENSOR = "fullSensor";

    public PluginResult execute(String action, JSONArray args, String callbackId) {
        if (action.equals("set")) {
            String orientation = args.optString(0);
            Activity activity = (Activity)this.cordova.getActivity();
            if (orientation.equals(UNSPECIFIED)) {
                activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED);
            } else if (orientation.equals(LANDSCAPE)) {
                activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
            } else if (orientation.equals(PORTRAIT)) {
                activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
            } else if (orientation.equals(USER)) {
                activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_USER);
            } else if (orientation.equals(BEHIND)) {
                activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_BEHIND);
            } else if (orientation.equals(SENSOR)) {
                activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR);
            } else if (orientation.equals(NOSENSOR)) {
                activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_NOSENSOR);
            } else if (orientation.equals(SENSOR_LANDSCAPE)) {
                activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE);
            } else if (orientation.equals(SENSOR_PORTRAIT)) {
                activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_PORTRAIT);
            } else if (orientation.equals(REVERSE_LANDSCAPE)) {
                activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_LANDSCAPE);
            } else if (orientation.equals(REVERSE_PORTRAIT)) {
                activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_PORTRAIT);
            } else if (orientation.equals(FULL_SENSOR)) {
                activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_FULL_SENSOR);
            }
            return new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK);
        } else {
            return new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.INVALID_ACTION);
        }
    }
}
```

JS file:

```js
var screenOrientation = function() {}
    screenOrientation.prototype.set = function(str, success, fail) {
    cordova.exec(success, fail, "ScreenOrientation", "set", [str]);
};
navigator.screenOrientation = new screenOrientation();
```

The execution of the script doesn't produce any error message at all so I don't know what's wrong. Thanks for helping out.

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to update this code to work with cordova 2.3.0 (haven't tested for compatibility with newer versions of cordova), enjoy:

java:

```
package org.apache.cordova.plugin;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;

import org.apache.cordova.api.CallbackContext;
import org.apache.cordova.api.CordovaPlugin;

public class ScreenOrientation extends CordovaPlugin {
    // Refer to http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#screenOrientation

    private static final String UNSPECIFIED = "unspecified";
    private static final String LANDSCAPE = "landscape";
    private static final String PORTRAIT = "portrait";
    private static final String USER = "user";
    private static final String BEHIND = "behind";
    private static final String SENSOR = "sensor";
    private static final String NOSENSOR = "nosensor";
    private static final String SENSOR_LANDSCAPE = "sensorLandscape";
    private static final String SENSOR_PORTRAIT = "sensorPortrait";
    private static final String REVERSE_LANDSCAPE = "reverseLandscape";
    private static final String REVERSE_PORTRAIT = "reversePortrait";
    private static final String FULL_SENSOR = "fullSensor";

    @Override
    public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) {
        if (action.equals("set")) {
            String orientation = args.optString(0);
            Activity activity = cordova.getActivity();
            if (orientation.equals(UNSPECIFIED)) {
                activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED);
            } else if (orientation.equals(LANDSCAPE)) {
                activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
            } else if (orientation.equals(PORTRAIT)) {
                activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
            } else if (orientation.equals(USER)) {
                activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_USER);
            } else if (orientation.equals(BEHIND)) {
                activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_BEHIND);
            } else if (orientation.equals(SENSOR)) {
                activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR);
            } else if (orientation.equals(NOSENSOR)) {
                activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_NOSENSOR);
            } else if (orientation.equals(SENSOR_LANDSCAPE)) {
                activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE);
            } else if (orientation.equals(SENSOR_PORTRAIT)) {
                activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_PORTRAIT);
            } else if (orientation.equals(REVERSE_LANDSCAPE)) {
                activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_LANDSCAPE);
            } else if (orientation.equals(REVERSE_PORTRAIT)) {
                activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_PORTRAIT);
            } else if (orientation.equals(FULL_SENSOR)) {
                activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_FULL_SENSOR);
            }
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

JS:

```
        //wait for cordova to load
        window.addEventListener("load",function(){
            document.addEventListener("deviceready",phonegapReady,false)
        });


        function phonegapReady(){

            //once cordova has loaded
            var screenOrientation = function() {}
            screenOrientation.prototype.set = function(str, success, fail) {
                cordova.exec(null, null, "ScreenOrientation", "set", [str]);
            };
            window.screenOrientation = new screenOrientation();

            //To change screen orientation use
            window.screenOrientation.set("landscape");
        };
```

you should also add to res/xml/config.xml

```
<plugin name="ScreenOrientation" value="org.apache.cordova.plugin.ScreenOrientation" />
```